# Why does `class-name` does not work in the REPL for this case?

Tags: oop, common-lisp, class-names

I am reading the book *Object Oriented Programming in Common Lisp* from Sonja Keene.

In chapter 7, the author presents:

```lisp
(class-name class-object)
```

This would make possible to query a class object for its name.

Using SBCL and the SLIME's REPL, I tried:

```lisp
; SLIME 2.26.1
CL-USER> (defclass stack-overflow () 
           ((slot-1 :initform 1 )
            (slot-2 :initform 2)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::STACK-OVERFLOW>
CL-USER> (make-instance 'stack-overflow)
#<STACK-OVERFLOW {1002D188E3}>
CL-USER> (defvar test-one (make-instance 'stack-overflow))
TEST-ONE
CL-USER> (slot-value test-one 'slot-1)
1
CL-USER> (class-name test-one)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-PCL::NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD-ERROR {10032322E3}>.
```

The code above returns the error message below:

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP:CLASS-NAME (1)>
when called with arguments
  (#<STACK-OVERFLOW {1003037173}>).
   [Condition of type SB-PCL::NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD-ERROR]
```

How would be the proper use of `class-name`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `class-name` must be a class object, not an instance of the class.

Use `class-of` to get the class of the instance, then you can call `class-name`

```
(class-name (class-of test-one))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Barmar's hint on a comment, this would the correct approach with `class-name`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (class-name (defclass stack-overflow () 
                       ((slot-1 :initform 1 )
                        (slot-2 :initform 2))))
STACK-OVERFLOW
```

`class-name` receives as an argument a class. In order to work with instances, the correct approach is using `class-of`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (class-of 'test-one)
#<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:SYMBOL>
```

I am not sure why `class-name` would be helpful, though.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be helpful?  Classes are objects.  One of their slots is their name.  That slot has a reader named `class-name`.  You need that when you're programmatically working with classes.  Go to your quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software directory and ag for class-name, then you will see how it is used.